# Prompt for gender only in certain locales

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I'm designing an iOS app using localized strings. Some of my strings include words that include gender suffixes in some languages.

I would like to prompt my users to specify whether they are male or female, but only when the device is using a language that requires gender pronouns.

How do I approach this? Should I attempt to detect the device's locale? Should I attempt to detect which localization bundle iOS selected? (How do I do that?)

Comment: It would be really weird to me to be asked, effectively, "What grammatical gender should we use when referring to you?" Languages that have grammatically distinct forms for different genders have come up with acceptable solutions of their own, similar to the English usage of "their", "he/she", or "s/he". Sometimes, clever rewriting can work around the need for such compromises entirely. Work with your translators on this.

Comment: I'm already prompting for the user's name; I was just going to toss in a "Male/Female" segmented control right next to that.

Comment: Male/Female/Androgynous/Other/It's a Long Story/Prefer Not to Answer?

Comment: What gender suffixes would you use in those other cases? Traditionally, gendered languages use the masculine gender for people whose gender is unknown. Is that really better? Have you thought this problem through, or are you just wishing that this problem would go away?

Comment: You would use whichever forms the person asks you to use, which might not have a simple relationship to their gender identity. In most cases, you can write around the problem. Where you cannot, each community of language speakers has developed its own approaches. See for example ["Gender-neutrality in languages with grammatical gender"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutrality_in_languages_with_grammatical_gender). You run into the same problem with languages that make a [T-V distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction).

Comment: @Jeremy. The "standard" way to phrase that question in English is "Which pronouns do you use?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSLocale systemLocale]` not surprisingly returns the locale that the system is set to.

You might however, be better querying the language that the user is using. You can do this by querying `NSUserDefaults` for the key 'AppleLanguages' and getting the first value from the returned array. This value is the user's chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` returns at position 0 the language as chosen by the user in the Settings App.

Comment: i would think this is preferable because the user may take their phone to different locales, and i want them to be reading my app text in their home language.